# Using $gt in Python

Tags: python, mongodb

In the Mongo shell, I'd normally write

```
db.mydb.find({"id":{$gt:"990000"}})
```

But how do I write $gt in a python script so I can find an element inside the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to put the `$gt` in quotes, as in:

```
db.mydb.find({"id": {"$gt": "990000"}})
```